# Upgrading from ASP.Net 2.0 to 4.0 WITHOUT visual studio

Tags: asp.net

**The Environment:**

Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise Edition
IIS 7.5.7600.26385

**The Problem:**
I have an existing web site currently running ASP.Net version 2.0 and want to move to ASP.Net 4.0.
I do NOT have Visual Studio so I cannot simply use an “upgrade wizard” to perform this task.
Here is what I have tried so far:

in IIS:

1. Create a new application pool name “aspnet_v40” and configured to use ASP.Net 4.0 (Integrated)
2. Stop the web site
3. Change web site to the new application pool (“aspnet_v40”)
4. Click on Web site “.Net Compile” option – IIS displays the following error:
   There was an error performing this operation
   \Windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\web.config
   Line #141
   Error: Unrecognized element 'folderLevelBuildProviders'

When logged into the server, I use the aspnet_regiis program to list and verify the versions of ASP.Net that are installed (I thought I would get the same answer from all directories, but below is what is reported):

**C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727>aspnet_regiis -lv**

2.0.50727.0     C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll

4.0.30319.0     c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll

2.0.50727.0     C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll

4.0.30319.0     c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll

**C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727>aspnet_regiis -lv**

2.0.50727.0     C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll

4.0.30319.0     c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll

2.0.50727.0     C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll

4.0.30319.0     c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll

**C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319>aspnet_regiis -lv**

2.0.50727.0     C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll

4.0.30319.0     c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll

4.0.30319.0     c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll

**C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319>aspnet_regiis -lv**

2.0.50727.0     C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll

4.0.30319.0     c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll

4.0.30319.0     c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll

Obviously, there are steps I am missing:

1. How to get rid of the the "Unrecognized element 'folderLevelBuildProviders'" error.
2. What are the steps (commands) required to move from 2.0 to 4.0 (ie: new or changed elements in web.config??)

Does anyone have a step-by-step guide for upgrading from 2.0 to 4.0 WITHOUT Visual Studio?
Or, does anyone have link to such a guide??

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you even want to upgrade if you don't access the source code? You could simply create an ApplicationPool that runs 2.0

Comment: I never said I don't have access to the source code -- I said I do not have access to Visual Studio.

Comment: Why do you want to use 4.0 for a 2.0 WebApplication, when the WebApplication doesn't use any of the 4.0 features?

Comment: I never said I don't want to use 4.0 features; I am upgrading so that I CAN use 4.0 features -- BUT FIRST (read original post) I have to get rid of the 'Unrecognized element 'folderLevelBuildProviders' error in IIS before I can even continue to upgrade the application -- I have found posts regarding the error, but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok -- FINALLY got things to work, below is the magic:

Check using appcmd.exe to list the isapiFilters that have been configured:

**C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv>appcmd.exe list config -section:system.webServer/isapiFilters**

```
<system.webServer>
  <isapiFilters>
    <filter name="ASP.Net_2.0.50727-64" path="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\aspnet_filter.dll" enableCache="true" preCondition="bitness64" />
    <filter name="ASP.Net_2.0.50727.0" path="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_filter.dll" enableCache="true" preCondition="bitness32" />
  </isapiFilters>
</system.webServer>
```

The above shows that the version 4.0 filters are NOT present, so I issue the following:

**C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319>aspnet_regiis -iru**

```
Start installing ASP.NET (4.0.30319).
....Finished installing ASP.NET (4.0.30319).
```

Now verify that version 4.0 is present:

**C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv>appcmd.exe list config -section:system.webServer/isapiFilters**

```
<filter name="ASP.Net_2.0.50727-64" path="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\aspnet_filter.dll" enableCache="true" preCondition="bitness64,runtimeVersionv2.0" />
<filter name="ASP.Net_2.0.50727.0" path="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_filter.dll" enableCache="true" preCondition="bitness32,runtimeVersionv2.0" />
<filter name="ASP.Net_2.0_for_V1.1" path="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_filter.dll" enableCache="true" preCondition="runtimeVersionv1.1" />
<filter name="ASP.Net_4.0_64bit" path="C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_filter.dll" enableCache="true" preCondition="runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" />
<filter name="ASP.Net_4.0_32bit" path="C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_filter.dll" enableCache="true" preCondition="runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" />
```

And now to update the site from version 2.0 to 4.0:

1. Create an application pool that uses version 4.0 –  be sure to set “Enable 32-Bit Applications” option to true if need be.
2. Stop the web site being upgraded.
3. Right-click on the web site -> Manage Web Site… -> Advanced Settings
4. Change the “Application Pool” to the version 4.0 application pool created in step 1.
   Click OK -> OK
5. Click on the ‘.Net Compilation” option and verify that the “Assemblies” section is using version 4.0.
6. Recompile web site DLL’s using the 4.0 framework and deposit in /bin directory.
7. Delete all files/folders in the web temporary directory (for holding temp asp.net files), This must be done otherwise access denied errors will be displayed when the web site is started.
8. Right-click on the web site -> Manage Web Site -> Start
9. Test all pages.

The above worked for me.

Comment: I cannot up vote this answer, as it is too localized for your own application. Microsoft already has documents available on the breaking changes, so using Visual Studio to perform upgrade and necessary changes is still critical for most developers. http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/aspnet4/breaking-changes

Comment: Your answer help me :)